How to reproduce PyMC-marketing DelayedSaturedMMM results?
I know that to reproduce results in pymc, you have to set the random_seed when sampling.
However, in pymc-marketing DelayedSaturedMMM, when I fix the random seed when fitting the model and when predicting, I always get new results.
I tried to set the random_seed here:
mmm.fit(X=X, y=y, target_accept=0.85, chains=4, nuts_sampler="numpyro", random_seed=42)

and here:
mmm.predict(X=X, random_seed=42)

And I still get different results every time.

Do you mean you get different y values on the same X when you run mmm.fit() and mmm.predict()? Then it is likely because passing the sampler to mmm.fit(nuts_sampler="numpyro", ...) does not persist the sampler choice in the model object. The default sampler will thus be used when mmm.predict() is run, leading to different results. To fix the sampler, you need to pass it in the sampler.config dict when you instantiate the MMM object.
